# Time series forecast with Kalman Filters in R-Cran

Tags: r, filter, kalman-filter

Can anybody point me to a well documented example, step-by-step on how to forecast a time series with Kalman Filters in R?

I have no particular preference for the package/library so it can be DSE or SSPIR or KFAS, etc.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 3):

Your question looks like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8055/how-to-use-dlm-with-kalman-filtering-for-forecasting) and [that one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/r-code-for-time-series-forecasting-using-kalman-filter) on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), and it seems they have what you need.